# Unresolved android dependency issue

Tags: android, android-studio

Hi I am new to Android Studio and I am using **Android studio 2.2.1.**
When I am trying to create a new project I am getting the the errors as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Click on "Install repository and sync project" links and then retry

Comment: @Sourabh Pal plz  click on install Repository and sync project

Comment: @MatPag  i tried that before but when I am trying to click on that link nothing happens. It doesn't install anything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the dependencies.
Find the the SDK Manager and download the yellow ones which are the most importants

[image]

If you still have problems, try to follow the official guide [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html)

Comment: I  tried following all that but it still didn't work so I installed android studio again and it is working for me again. It asked me to update the sdk before starting so it is working fine now.